# Mongoose one-to-many

Tags: node.js, mongoose, routes

can you explain me how to organize mongoose models to create one to many connections? It is needed keep separate collections.

suppose i have stores and items

//store.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Store', {
    name : String,
    itemsinstore: [ String]
});
```

//item.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', {
    name : String,
    storeforitem: [String]
 });
```

Am i doing it in the right way?

And how to access pass data to arryas?
Here is the code yo enter name to item. But how to enter id to array of id's (itemsinstore)?

```
app.post('/api/stores', function(req, res) {
    Store.create({
        name: req.body.name,
    }, function(err, store) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use model reference and `populate()` method:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Define your models:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var storeSchema = Schema({
   name : String,
   itemsInStore: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }]
});
var Store = mongoose.model('Store', storeSchema);

var itemSchema = Schema({
    name : String,
    storeForItem: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Store' }]
});
var Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

Save a new item into an existing store:

```
var item = new Item({name: 'Foo'});
item.save(function(err) {

  store.itemsInStore.push(item);
  store.save(function(err) {
    // todo
  });
});
```

Get items from a store

```
Store
  .find({}) // all
  .populate('itemsInStore')
  .exec(function (err, stores) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    // Stores with items
});
```

Comment: Should `store` in `store.itemsInStore.push(item)` be `Store`(capitalized) ? I don't see `store` defined. Just learning.

Comment: No, you should initialize a new one with `var store = new Store({})` and save it, of course. Or fetch one from database.

Comment: Ok so if I i wanted to add a new item in store `a`(example) I would do `var store = Store.find({name : "a"})` **inside** the  `item.save`. Now `store` will be the document that has the field `name` and the value `a` and now I could push the item into that particular document's `itemsInStore` array. I hope I make sense.

Comment: @Festo In itemSchema, storeForItem needs to be an array ? assuming that an item belongs to a store. It not should be just an object of type ObjectId, similar to 1-n relationship databases.
PD. Sorry for the poor English

Comment: According to MongoDB documentation, using this approach isn't a good idea if the itemsInStore need to be unbounded. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents

Comment: . . G E N I U S .  .

Answer (score 17):

You can do using the best practices with [Virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals).

**Store.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const StoreSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

StoreSchema.virtual('items', {
    ref: 'Item',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'storeId',
    justOne: false // set true for one-to-one relationship
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Store', StoreSchema)
```

**Item.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    storeId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema)
```

**StoreController.js**

```
const Store = require('Store.js')

module.exports.getStore = (req, res) => {
    const query = Store.findById(req.params.id).populate('items')

    query.exec((err, store) => {
        return res.status(200).json({ store, items: store.items })
    })
}
```

Keep in mind that virtuals are not included in `toJSON()` output by default. If you want populate virtuals to show up when using functions that rely on `JSON.stringify()`, like Express' `res.json()` [function](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json), set the `virtuals: true` option on your schema's `toJSON` options.

```
// Set `virtuals: true` so `res.json()` works
const StoreSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } });
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the hint about `toJSON`. I was stuck there and wondering why my response does not include the freaking children

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is how you define a dependancy:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    name : String,
    itemsinstore: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }]
});
```

And make sure you have different names:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', {
    name : String,
    storeforitem: [String]
 });
```

Keep an eye on `Item` in both cases.

And then you just want to pass the array of ObjectIDs in it. See more here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Store.findOne({_id:'5892b603986f7a419c1add07'})
  .exec (function(err, store){
    if(err) return res.send(err);

   var item = new Item({name: 'Foo'});
   item.save(function(err) {

   store.itemsInStore.push(item);
   store.save(function(err) {
    // todo
 });
});
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer - just dumping code with no commentary whatsoever is *not* a good way to write an answer.