# How to include schema of other model in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 schema `products` and `orders` as shown below:

`products.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   const productsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    prod_name : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    qty : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price : {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    }
});
mongoose.model('Products', productsSchema);
```

`orders.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ProductsModel = mongoose.model('Products');

const OrdersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    order_date : {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    sum : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    products: [ProductsModel]
});

const Orders = module.exports = mongoose.model('Orders', OrdersSchema);
```

`app.js` where am referencing the files

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

const contact = require('./routes/contacts');
const product = require('./routes/products');
const order = require('./routes/orders');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlist')
const port = 3000;
app.use('/contacts', contact);
app.use('/products', product);
app.use('/orders', order);
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started at port ' + port);
})
```

In above `orders.js` am trying to include products schema and its giving below error

`MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Products".`

I want to store array of products in same orders schema.

Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code where you integrate `products.js` and `orders.js` ?

Comment: updated the question with latest `products.js` and `orders.js`

Comment: Please show where do you include those files

Comment: please check for the updated question

Answer (score 0):

To have a reusable mongoose model you should export the schema as a model
like the following code:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    prod_name : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    qty : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price : {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', productsSchema);
```

Comment: but how to declare `products` array in orders schema

Comment: @Rocky read about the [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in mongo and read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245685/mongoose-one-to-many/35245953).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you forgot to use `new` which creates a new Schema.

Try changing :

```
const productsSchema = mongoose.Schema
```

To :

```
const productsSchema = new mongoose.Schema
```

In `orders.js` you will be able to get the schema like this :

`mongoose.model('Products').schema`